# ¿Como retornar datos a tiempo con una petición GET en ionic 2?

Tags: http, ionic2

Tengo un problema al hacer una petición **GET**, me retorna los datos tarde, como hago para corregir esto.

Aquí les dejo el código

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the ServiProductos provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class ServiProductos {
    productos;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ServiProductos Provider');
  }
getDatos(){

    this.http.get("http://mercado.000webhostapp.com/v1/productos").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data  => {

      this.productos=data;
    }));
    return this.productos;

  }
```

Comment: A que te refieres con "tarde" se demora demasiado?

Comment: Me refiero a que cuando trato de usar los datos que retorna, me aparecen undefined

Comment: Haaa, puedes imprimir el valor de `data` ?

Comment: Hago un console.log(data); y a la consola llega toda la información, el problema es que esta llegando después de que la view intenta mostrar los datos, en el constructor de la view hago un console.log(); con la variable donde almaceno la información que retorna la función getDatos(); justo después del llamado, y en consola me llega undefined